# Wget download FTP files

Tags: linux, wget

i want to wget all the files from  server A(file directory is /file A...) to another server.

server A file directory is

```
/file A
 file B/file c
 file D
```

i used the following command:

```
wget --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=psd ftp://ip/*
```

it download all files but not folder.how to download all of them. namely the above only download file A ,  file D. not download  file B/file c.
how to download all of the files. thank u

There is a new problem, there is a folder named content/upload/2014/1/some images. the images in this folder don't be downloaded. why. –

Answer (score 2):

add `-r` option :

```
wget -r -l 6 --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=psd ftp://ip/*
```

Comment: There is a new problem, there is a folder named content/upload/2014/1/some images.  the images in this folder don't be downloaded. why.

Comment: add -l option for maximum depth to for example 6

Comment: the image are all 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

The solution (which I am currently using) is:

```
wget --ftp-user=USER --ftp-password=PASSWORD --level=20 ftp://IP:PORT/*
```

Where of course you have to replace USER, PASSWORD, IP, and PORT.  If the FTP server is running on a conventional port, you can just omit ":PORT", I am running a server (on my phone) on port 2221.

Oddly, -r causes it to fail entirely, but specifying the level seems to work.